# converted date time in json

Tags: json, jquery

i have a model,with jason send and fill this model but
when return a filled model by data and get it in view date time converted to :"/Date(1241465400000)/"

```
[Serializable]
public class MyModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public DateTime date {get;set;}
}

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SchedulesDropdownIndexChanged(MyModel schedule)
    {
        objScheduleModel = new ScheduleModel();
        objScheduleModel = schedule;

         ......fill model here date time is ok-----------
          objScheduleModel.date=Datetime.Now;

        return Json(objScheduleModel);
    }
```

here is a dropdownlist when selected index chaned fired this function

```
$(function () {
  $("select#SchedulesDropdown").change(function (evt) {
    var ScheduleModel = getScheduleDateTime();
    var json = $.toJSON(ScheduleModel);
    var abc;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Members/DropdownIndexChanged",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (msg) {


            var o = msg.date;---------------unformated date time--------------->>> "/Date(1241465400000)/"

        }
    });
});
```

});

```
function getScheduleDateTime() {
   var Id = $("select#SchedulesDropdown").val();
   var to = $("#dateTo").val();
   return (Id == "") ? null : { Id: Id, date: to };
```

}

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery extension to auto convert dates

[This blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/converting-dates-in-json-strings-using.html) might help. It's an extension that auto converts ISO as well as Asp.net dates.

I also suggest if you use this code to make the optional parameter to **disable** auto conversion so by default it simply converts dates. In your case (because you're not explicitly calling `parseJSON`) this will just convert it. And 99.9% of the time you do want auto conversion all the time.